# Summing more than two doubles

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming.
Anyone please help me writing the code for summing more than two double/float numbers.

Comment: Just use `+` more times?

Comment: You should provide your current code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    float x = 10.5;
    float y = 13.4;
    float z = 12.7;
    float a = 52.0; 
    float sum = (x + y + z + a);
    System.out.println("Your sum is:" + sum);
```